# Setting wallpaper using onclick event of a button has no effect

Tags: android, wallpaper

I'm following the [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/03/set-wallpaper-using-wallpapermanager.html) trying to set the wallpaper using onclick event of a button.

My code for that is,

```
private OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){

        setBg();}

    public void setBg(){
        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
         = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
         myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.shrek);
        } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

       }
```

Also i've set the permission SETWALLPAPER.

But when i click, Nothing happens.

whats the problem here?

Comment: Have you register your listener object with your button ?
like button.setonclickListener(your_listener_obj);

Comment: ya did pal. Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
  start.setOnClickListener(startListener);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this tutorial, he uses the OnClickListener a bit different:
`buttonSetWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){....`

Try this, should work:

```
start.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) { 
    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    try {
     myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.shrek);
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }});
```

EDIT:
Of course you can also just call your method in OnClick instead of handling it directly

Comment: Try logging something above   `myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.shrek);`
Then you´ll know what works and what doesnt